# Cannot get dependencys injected into Signalr Hub Using Autofac

Tags: dependency-injection, signalr, autofac, signalr-hub

How do I get Autofac to inject dependencies into the signalr hubs, I have tried all the only questions many of which are now out of date, I have tried the signalr.autofac download from their site, but nothing seems to work?

My Autofac

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

//Register Context
builder.Register(c => new myContext()).As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

//Repositories
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(BaseRepository<>)).As(typeof(IBaseRepository<>)).InstancePerHttpRequest();           

//Service Layer
builder.RegisterType<UserService>().As<IUserService>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

//other services etc

builder.RegisterType<ChatHub>(); 

var container = builder.Build();           

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));          

GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
```

The dependency revolver I get from the autofac web site;

http://code.google.com/p/autofac/downloads/detail?name=Autofac.SignalR.3.0.0.zip

but I get;

> No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the
>   scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates
>   that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by
>   a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web
>   integration always request dependencies from the
>   DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime,
>   never from the container itself.

Comment: Please post the code what you have so far? How do you build your container how do you create and setup the dependency resolver? etc.

Comment: Code has been updated, the hub is just a hub with a service interface being added, I can post the code if needed, not sure if anything else is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution from autofac, not perfect but it works:

http://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=416

Answer (score 0):

Worth a try, maybe this new docs page can help you finding your issue:
https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/SignalRIntegration